# How to access Salesforce api through third party application?

Tags: api, salesforce

I am working on a cloud based application, I am assigned the work to implement Salesforce API in my application. I am done with all the authentication process and I am even able to push the leads in api.

But the problem is that I can only authorize my developer account thru it, the account from which I have taken consumer key and secret.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an package with your remote access settings (aka key & secret) and install it into the other org(s).

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply ... But I am able to generate the consumer key and secret and placing it in my org(s) setting along with the login url and redirect url. Everything is working fine till the tym I login with the username from which I have generated the key and secret but when I try to login thru my 3rd party app with an other username its able to login but after it redirects to an error page saying : Remote Access Authorization Error
         There was a problem in setting up your remote access
with an outh_error_code=1800 !!!

Comment: Your key is only in the one org that you created it in, it won't work in any other orgs until you make an appexchange package that includes the key, and install the package into the other org.

Comment: ok... I tried ur method but cnt find out how to make an appexchange package and how to install it? I will highly thankful if u provide me with the link or some documentation . . .  Thanks a lot for ur reply

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334583/how-to-make-an-appexchange-package-that-includes-the-key